# How to bring segments in morris.js bar chart close to each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

How do you bring segments in morris.js bar chart close to each other? Below, the left one is what morris.js offers by default, but I would like to have the one on the right where segments are close to each other. The [documentation](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html) doesn't specify such option. Do you know how I can achieve this?

[image: this] [image: this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source of Morris.js, you can use the option **barGap**. Its default value is 3, you can try with a lower value. Also you can use the option **barSizeRatio** (default value: 0.75) in order to adjust width between 2 rows of data.